# Advice on display special characters

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

As intro.. 
my program read raw data from an input file.. then the program will extract, reformat and do necessary checking/filter and stored in MySQL.

The following is sample data stored in MySQL. FYI, I can't find better option than to stored the values to make it look good on display.

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| ID  | DATA                                                                                           | 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1   | Carol&nbsp;and&nbsp;Anna&nbspare&nbsp;best&nbsp;friends<br>They&nbsp;grew&nbsp;up&nbsp;together|
| 2   | They&nbsp;go&nbsp;to&nbsp;same&nbsp;school<br>They&nbsp;have&nbsp;same&nbsp;hobby.             |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

There some circumstances why i need to store the

```
&nbsp;  and  < br >
```

into MySQL.
So, when i want to display it.. i just simply print it and it will appear as expected as follows:

1   Carol and Anna are best friends 
       They grew up together

2   They go to same school 
       They have same hobby

All looks good until I have data that contain special character tags such as < > or /. For example.. if i store. Carol says "That's so funny". < Carol laugh >. The words "Carol laugh" inside  < > are not display on screen.

My questions are.. do we have a way to display it? or is there any option to store the data? if i use htmlspecialchars() or htmlentities(), it will display together all my   and < br >

i need to store those &nbsp and < br > because there are texts that are purposely contain blanks/white spaces.

Any idea guys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `html_entity_decode` at the time of display the html text.

**html_entity_decode** — Convert all HTML entities to their applicable characters

Ex:

```
<?php
$orig = "I'll \"walk\" the <b>dog</b> now";

$b = html_entity_decode($orig);
echo $b; // I'll "walk" the <b>dog</b> now
```

[Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)

Comment: I've tried and value inside < > still not displayed

Comment: 'for($i = 0; $i < count($lines); $i++)
                                          {
                                                print '<tr>';
                                                print '<td>'.$title[$i].'</td>';
                                                print '<td class="numeric">Bit-'.$bitnum[$i].'</td>';
                                                print '<td>['.html_entity_decode($lines[$i]).']</td>';
                                                print '</tr>';                                           
                                            }'

Comment: i display the output in a table. $lines are the contents / statements that may contain special characters

Comment: Check this example: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5d60569da7dae595c3c26955c6113b2a2172d73f

Comment: no its not.. Original text is "Carol says "It's funny". <Carol laughs>". Text stored in MySQL is "Carol&nbspsays&nbsp"It's&nbspfunny".&nbsp<Carol&nbsplaughs>" And text display on screen is "Carol says "It's funny." Missing text in < >

Comment: i think it's work.. but i may need to check my contents.. Thanks a lot..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137509/discussion-between-mayank-pandeyz-and-julie).